# Kill all processes launched inside an xterm when exit

Tags: bash, cygwin, process-management

I'm using Cygwin to start some servers.

Each server is launched inside an xterm with a bunch of command like this one:
`xterm -e $my_cmd /C  &`

Is there an easy way to kill all launched children (xterm and their running commands) in a row ?

I want also to be able kill a particular launched command when I close its parent xterm.

Someone knows how to perform that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`killall xterm`? That command is in the *psmisc* package. Xterm will notify its child process with a `SIGHUP` ("hangup") before it exits. Normally that will cause the child process to exit too, although some servers interpret that signal differently.

Comment: killall xterm is too violent: that kills other xterm that should be left alone. And the children processes re not killed...

Comment: In that case I guess you'll need to write a script that combs through `/proc` to find the appropriate processes to kill.

Comment: Oh, and you did ask "Is there an easy way to kill *all* launched xterm".

Comment: yeah, I fix it ;).But my title is: Kill all processes launched inside an xterm when exit

Comment: Is it possible to kill a node-pty process and respawn a new node-pty terminal?